# Book from the 80s or 90s set in an abandoned Catskills hotel

Tags: identification-request

I think the book was from the 80’s or 90’s. Plot was about a brother and sister. Their stepfather or father tries to molest the sister and the kids escape and end up finding an abandoned(or so they thought) Catskills hotel where they decide to hide out. An older man or woman still resides at the hotel and the three form a bond. I think the dad/stepdad eventually tracks them down.

Comment: Welcome to the site! There's a checklist in the [ID tag info](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) which may help to jog your memory for more details. Presumably, given the mention of the Catskills, this book was set in the USA and written in English? Can you remember anything about the size of the book (novel, short story, novella)? How old were the brother and sister? Was it a kids' book, YA, or for adults?

Comment: Kenn, if an answer is the book you're looking for you can click the checkmark under the voting arrows to "accept" that answer. This marks the question as solved.

Answer (score 5):

[Someone's Watching](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/481430.Someone_Watching) by Andrew Neiderman

> Marty, age seventeen, and Judy, age fourteen, become stepbrother and
> stepsister when their parents marry. When Marty’s father attempts to
> attack Judy, Marty beats him off. The pair flee to a nearby, seemingly
> deserted old resort in the Catskills, where they discover the owner
> still living as if the hotel were about to open. They participate in
> the old man’s fantasy to keep themselves safe, carrying on a Romeo and
> Juliet romance, unaware they are constantly being watched…